# create worksheet with common values from two other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two workbooks with lots of overlapping values. They have a common column  that serves as a unique identifier.  I need to make a third worksheet with rows that only exist in both of the source worksheets, using the ID field as a join. Example:

Sheet 1:

| ID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | Letterman |
| 2 | George | Carlin |
| 3 | Richard | Pryor |

Sheet 2:

| ID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | Letterman |
| 3 | Richard | Pryor |
| 4 | Eddie | Murphy |

Target sheet:

| ID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | Letterman |
| 3 | Richard | Pryor |

Comment: I feel like this should be easy. In SQL it's like "SELECT * FROM table, table2 where table1.id = table2.id"

Comment: If you have Excel 365 then you can use Power Query to `Merge` your tables on ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you create Excel Tables in your sheets
Table1 in Sheet1 and Table2 in Sheet2
you can simply use FILTER function

```
=FILTER(Table1,COUNTIF(Table2[ID],Table1[ID]))
```

Column headers should be copied separately or you can use additionally [#All] qualifier.

```
=FILTER(Table1[#All],COUNTIF(Table2[[#All],[ID]],Table1[[#All],[ID]]))
```